# Mostrar div que contém conteúdo de pesquisa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu criei um botão de pesquisa e algumas opções de pesquisa dentro das divs `.opcao`. Como eu faço para que apareçam apenas as `divs` em que o conteúdo do botão contenha as palavras digitadas no campo de busca?

Por exemplo, se eu digitar 'cadastrar' devem aparecer apenas as divs com os conteúdos dos botões `cadastrar novo cliente`, `cadastrar novo funcionário` e `cadastrar novo produto`.

```html
<input type="search" name="q" class="search-text" placeholder="Procurar..." autocomplete="off" id="textFind">
<div class="pesquisas">
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de clientes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de fornecedores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo fornecedor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de produtos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo produto</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o seletor **[:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**. Ele vai buscar apenas os elementos que tiverem o texto digitado no input. Como o `:contains` é *case sensitive* (diferencia maiúsculo de minúsculo), você pode alterar o comportamento do seletor via código:

```js
$(function(){
   $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(a){
      return function(e){
         return ~$(e).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase());
      }
   });
   $("[name=q]").on("input", function(){
      $(".opcao").hide();
      $(".opcao:contains('"+ this.value +"')").show();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" name="q" class="search-text" placeholder="Procurar..." autocomplete="off" id="textFind">
<div class="pesquisas">
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Agenda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de clientes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo cliente</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de fornecedores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo fornecedor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Lista de produtos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="opcao">
        <a>Cadastrar novo produto</a>
        <x></x>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tem um exemplo com Jquery:

```js
$('.contact-name').hide();
$('#search').click(function(){
    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.contact-name').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
           $(this).show();
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Charles Smith</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">raj kumar</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Charles Smith</a></h3></div>
```